# Is there a tool to migrate a SQL Express Database to SQL CE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Are there any tools available (prefer if free) to transfer tables and data from SQL Express 2005 to SQL CE 3.5?

I have a small app that uses SQL Express and since it is using Linq-to-SQL I want to change it to use SQL CE 3.5 so that users don't need to install the DB engine in order to use it and to simplify backups having them only copy the .sdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need the same yesterday.
Googling I have found two options:

Better Option:
[Primeworks Data Port Wizard](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortWizard.html)

Works great for me. Is full trial for 30 days

An option that didn't work for me:

Johny Cant Code Exporter free (google it, SO dont letme post another link)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use my Export2SqlCe tool (also part of SQL Server Compact Toolbox) - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html